# Are convergent sequences path-connected in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the subset of convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, is this set path-connected in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ with the product topology?

I believe that this is true, however, I was not able to find a continuous path between two convergent sequences. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: For given two sequences $a_n, b_n$ define $c(t)_n = ta_n + (1-t)b_n$. Here you go, $c(t)$ is the path you are looking for. You owe me a beer. ;)

Comment: Which product topology? Box product, Tychonoff product, or uniform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$ be convergent sequences, converging to $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then $(1-t)a_n + t b_n$ is a convergent sequence for any $t \in [0,1]$, converging to $(1-t)a + tb$.

So a possible path connecting $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{b_n\}$ is given by:
$$ t \mapsto \{(1-t)a_n + t b_n \}$$

Since $$ t \mapsto (1-t)a_1 + tb_1, \ \ , t \mapsto (1-t)a_2 + tb_2, \ \ t \mapsto (1-t)a_3 + tb_3, \ \ \dots $$ are all continuous functions from $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, our path $ t \mapsto \{(1-t)a_n + t b_n \}$ is indeed a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to the space $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ endowed with the product topology. [This follows from the fact that any function to a product space is continuous iff the compositions of the function with the projections onto each component of the product space are all continuous.]